# React "pass back" callback (as state?)

Tags: reactjs, callback, state

I have two react components: Filter and UseFilter (and a Parent). Filter displays a number of filter options and produces a callback which can filter items according to the set options. How can I pass back a callback and store it as state in the parent?

```
function Parent() {
    const [cb, setCb] = useState(defaultCb);

    return (
        <>
            <Filter onChange={setCb}></Filter>
            <UseFilter filter={cb}></UseFilter>
        </>
    );
}

function Filter({ onChange }) {
    const [checkboxState, setCheckboxState] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        onChange((item) => {
            return item.boolProp == checkboxState;
        });
    }, [checkboxState]);

    return <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => setCheckboxState(e.target.checked)} />;
}
```

Like this?

I am not sure if this code snippet is correct. Can you save callbacks as a state? How would I use useCallback in this case?